# Where find Magento 2 modules list

Tags: magento2

My task is estimate costs of technical implementation of Magento 2 (Open Source version) for my client. To to that I need to find list of modules / features installed by default. Where I can find them ??

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Log in to Magento 2 installation root folder: use SSH via Terminal or Putty.cd;
2. Run below command to see a full list of enabled or disabled Magento 2 extensions:

   `php bin/magento module:status`

You’ll get the list as follows:

[image: module listing]

Comment: thanks   [Timon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2117444/timon-de-groot/).

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3
System > Web Setup Wizard > Module Manager

Magento 2.2
Stores > Configuration > Advanced

Comment: May I know the way to view installed extensions in magento 2.4.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can check all installed modules with the `bin/magento module:status` CLI command. Also, the list of installed modules can be found in `app/etc/config.php` file. Hope this helps.